# Top layer for two applications in one

Tags: web, administration

I have to rebuild an application that contains two main functionalities (administrating folders and groups). Both are totally different things, cannot be combined, and will be reconstructed with different design approaches.

My problem: Both functionalities / apps will be in the same web app in the end. I am now a little bit blocked, because I don't know how to build a top layer page above those two applications.

In the current app it is solved like this:
[image: Wireframe showing Groups and Folders sections on a page]

But I am not really happy about that. Does anybody have a good idea or an example where they have faced the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will your user be switching back and forth between the two, or do you think it's more like you have a persona who is in Groups all day, and a persona in Folders, and they rarely cross?

Comment: What does top nav-bar contain in this top layer page? How is the navigation done inside each of the apps?

Comment: Why aren't you happy with the current design? Can you elaborate on that? Are there any problems or is it just an aesthetic matter?

Answer (score 4):

I like the way Google does it. They have a button in the navbar where you can switch from one product to the other. You would have to decide if there is an empty page for entry or if one product is the default one to be shown when the user goes to myuxapp.io.

[image: Screenshot of google products]

Comment: Thanks Nash. Cool idea. Thanks. Apple has a similar approach (https://static.giga.de/wp-content/uploads/2025/07/icloud_uebersicht.jpg), but Google and Apple has multiple apps. I only have 2 ...

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is how to include a large number of applications on a website, being only two applications, I don't think there is more inconvenience than finding a good design that is understandable for all types of users.

The example in the question is an option: two mega-buttons with access to each application.

I would not hesitate to explore any option by exaggerating any possibility.

##### Solution #1

Two mega-tabs hanging from the top, clearly distinguishable in color and shape, leaving no room for doubt about their use and functionality.

[image: mega tabs]

##### Solution #2

Implementing a *tab navigation* to group and isolate each app and allowing to browse each one separately, while staying on the same page.

[image: tab navigation]

*Working example: [vinetrail.co.uk](https://www.vinetrail.co.uk/)*

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the navigation works inside each app, you could show two panels with  shortcuts to the most important/most used options of each application and a button to access the main page.

[image: Panels with shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you always provide a good experience no matter what the scale. And also always strive for scalability.
You never know how many new apps can be added in the future.

[image: Example showing 2 app dashboard]